# installing Theano with Enthought Canopy on Windows

Tags: python, windows, theano-cuda

I'm trying to install Theano, here is my situation.

The system is Windows 10 (64-bit), with CUDA 7.5 installed with Visual Studio 2013. The Python distribution is Enthought Canopy (2.7.10, 32-bit) with pip, numpy (1.9.2-3) and scipy (0.17.0-2).

The installation is as follows, 
1. install Theano (0.7) with pip;
2. install mingw (4.8.1-2) and libpython (1.2) using enpkg tool;
3. copy the newly created libpython27.a into ${PYTHONHOME}/Libs;
4. edit and save .theanorc.txt under c:\users\${myName} as

```
[global]
devive=gpu
floatX=float32

[blas]
ldflags=${PYTHONHOME}\Scripts -lmk2_core -lmk2_intel_thread -lmk2_rt

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\libs
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

[gcc]
cxxflags=
```

When I try to import theano, I get the following warning and error:

> mod.cu(1019): warning: statement is unreachable
>
> mod.cu(1019): warning: statement is unreachable
>
> mod.cu
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cublas.lib'
>
> ['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\libs', '--compiler-bindir', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m32', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=11b90075e2397c684f9dc0f7276eab8f,-D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda', '-IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include', '-IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\include', '-o', 'C:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_71_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-32\cuda_ndarray\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\EGG-INFO\mingw\usr\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib', '-LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\libs', '-LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86', '-lpython27', '-lcublas', '-lcudart']
>
> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 2, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\libs --compiler-bindir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m32 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=11b90075e2397c684f9dc0f7276eab8f,-D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda -IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\include -o C:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_71_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-2.7.10-32\cuda_ndarray\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\EGG-INFO\mingw\usr\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86\libs -LC:\Users\${myName}\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86 -lpython27 -lcublas -lcudart')
>
> WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavilable)

I'm wondering if it's the 32-bit Python vs 64-bit system that causes the problem.

Comment: regarding the compile/link error, Yes, `-m32` tells `nvcc` to build a 32-bit executable.  There is no 32-bit version of `cublas.lib` included in CUDA 7.5.  Notice of the removal of 32-bit cublas was actually given in the [CUDA 7.0 release notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/doc/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf) " the following features are no longer supported by the CUDA
driver or CUDA toolkit: ... ‣ 32-bit versions of the CUDA Toolkit scientific libraries, including cuBLAS,
cuSPARSE, cuFFT, cuRAND, and NPP".  the WARNING ... gpu is not available is a separate issue

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks, I switched to the 64-bit Python and it worked

Comment: @chouzhupk: Please add a short answer describing your solution

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert point out in the comment, the warning suggests compatibility issue. I finally solved the problem by installing the 64-bit Enthought Canopy python distribution, the other steps are the same as described in the question.

It's worth mentioning that mingw can be installed by Enthough Canopy package manager as well, so you don't have to download independent mingw if you are using the distribution.